# NHibernate Criteria query time inner join

Tags: nhibernate, inner-join, criteria

Is it possible in NHibernate to inner join objects during query time with Criteria?

I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT p
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Section s
    ON   p.sid = s.id 
    AND  p.companyid = s.companyid
```

The join isn't in the mapping (and can't be there). 
Is there something like the following syntax?

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "p")
.CreateCriteria(typeof(Section), "s")
.Add(Expression.EqProperty("p.SectionId", "s.Id"))
.Add(Expression.EqProperty("p.CompanyId", "s.CompanyId"))
.List();
```

Is this at all possible? I can't use detachedcriteria here because I have two properties I'm using for joining.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, you can use a detachedquery.

I used the following:

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "p")
             .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("SectionId", typeof(Section), "s")
                    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"))
                    .Add(Expression.EqProperty("s.Id", "p.SectionId"))
                    .Add(Expression.EqProperty("s.CompanyId", "p.CompanyId"))
                )).List();
```

Which generates an in query which does the same as the inner join.

If you have any "nicer" alternatives, please feel free to share.